# Blocking IP automatically based on accessed files

Tags: php, apache, security

So I've got a Laravel-powered website that's just about launching, and I have an emailer set up that emails me whenever a 404 error is triggered on the site (as a phase-1 measure, to make sure no broken links are on the site).

Recently I got a slew of emails reporting 404s for a number of URLs:

- /wordpress/wp-admin
- /wp-admin
- /wp-admin/images/wordpress-logo.png
- /manager/media/script/mootools/mootools.js
- /templates/system/style.css
- /modules/system/system.css

All originating from the same remote IP, which I whoised to find that it belongs in Russia.

Now, I know what this means: some hacker/bot is putting out feelers to try and guess what the site is built on, presumably to then make the appropriate attack.

My question is, is it possible for me to automate the following process:

1. Track the 404-URLs being pinged (which arguably is already being done)
2. If a certain combination (e.g. the WP logo and the Joomla system CSS) URLs are being attempted, block this IP address.

Further notes:

- my server is running Ubuntu (Apache)
- I have full sudo access

Answer (score 1):

**Option one - manually editing .htaccess**

Most simply, you could manually add an IP to a `.htaccess` file with the following lines:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from 
192.168.0.1, 
192.168.0.2
. . .
```

**Option two - using application logic and a database table**

A more complex solution, based on some rules, could be achieved by keeping a table in your database - or you could use a JSON file or something similar - which would have a column for:

1. url that has been hit.
2. the ip address of the person that hit that url.

Everytime a user hits a 404, you record their ip with `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` and the url trying to be accessed. Each time, you check if that IP already exists in the table, and run some logic to check if they need to be added to the `.htaccess` file with:

```
$f = fopen(".htaccess", "w+");
fwrite($f, "192.168.0.1");
fclose($f);
```

Your 404 errors would have to be processed by your application, rather than by apache.

**Option three - fail2ban**

Finally, as another option, you could also use [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) which simply does all this for you.

Good luck! :)

Answer (score -1):

fail2ban or mod_security would be the best solutions for your own server.